# glxinfo | grep OpenGL not showing nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I just installed Ubuntu 19.10, ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, already have nvidia drivers installed, but I don't know why when I run `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` it doesn't show nothing about nvidia.

```
victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ sudo prime-select query
nvidia

victor7095@victor7095-Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: X.Org
OpenGL renderer string: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.33.0, 5.3.0-24-generic, LLVM 9.0.0)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.2.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Comment: AMD internal GPU are not compatible with PRIME yet.

Comment: @Pilot6 So it isn't possible to change OpenGL vendor to nvidia yeT

Comment: Well, it's kind of possible. In most cases it works, but there are other issues. What happens if you run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL`? And did you rboot after selecting Nvidia in Prime?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that prime-select feature is it doesn't work for amd/nvidia but only for intel/nvidia, so I had to manually config some files.

Basically I had to edit 2 files

1. `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf`

   In this one, I replaced the line with `Driver "amdgpu"` with `Driver "modesetting"`
2. `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf`

   I added a new line inside `OutputClass`: `Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"`

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1660 Ti with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 435.21
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

These instructions were given [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1067083/linux/nvidia-xconfig-doesnt-do-what-i-want-it-to-nor-does-nvidia-settings/post/5404726/#5404726). So now I was able to see the correct output of glxinfo.

Comment: Please add details of that manual to your answer. Now it is a link-only answer, that will be deleted according to the site rules.

Comment: And beware that now both adapters will consume power ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I already tried using [oibaf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjNn9ehjtbmAhXlHrkGHXaZCksQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2F~oibaf%2F%2Barchive%2Fubuntu%2Fgraphics-drivers&usg=AOvVaw2hRl6hp4SO7u_lwmFgZHXa) drivers, yet the power consumption was always very high when nvidia drivers were supposed to be off.